# Ввод своей строки

Tags: java

Задача в том, что бы считать количество символов в заданной строке и выводить это количество на экран. Но я не могу разобраться как мне вводить свою строку через консоль, это должно быть что-то по типу : `Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Ввод строки");

    String str = new String("Hi, how are you Jesse Pinkman?");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i77 = 0; i77 < str.length(); i77++) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Количество -  " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: А какие методы есть у Scanner?

Comment: а что находится в ``str.length()``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получение данных с консоли, лично мне известны 2 способа.

1. `Scanner`
2. `BufferedReader`

**SCANNER**

Для создания объекта сканера используется след. конструкция
`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`.
И для того чтобы считать данные с консоли используется метод `nextLine`.
Выглядит это так `String line = scanner.nextLine();`.

https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/klass-scanner

**BUFFEREDREADER**

Для создания объекта используется такая конструкция `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))`
Для чтения данных с консоли используется метод `readLine` выглядит это так
`String line = reader.readLine()`

https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/593-bufferedreader-i-bufferedwritter